# Calculate monthly rolling user count

Tags: sql

I have a transaction data like this:

| User_ID | Purchase_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2022-08-02 |
| 12231 | 2022-06-25 |
| 12231 | 2022-07-15 |
| 13421 | 2022-07-12 |
| 23132 | 2022-05-02 |
| 15231 | 2022-04-09 |

I want to calculate a monthly rolling unique count of users which updates on a weekly basis. The week must be a full week that starts from Monday to Sunday.

Here is the desired output:

| Unique_User_ID_Count | start_week_date | end_week_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 403 | 2022-07-04 | 2022-07-31 |
| 562 | 2022-06-27 | 2022-07-24 |
| 312 | 2022-06-20 | 2022-07-17 |

and so on.. data goes back 3 years

Using the code below, I am able to get the first row of the desired output but not sure how to get row 2 and 3 (and going back 3 years).

```
SELECT count(distinct user_id) as Unique_User_ID_Count, min(Purchase_Date) as start_week_date, max(Purchase_Date) as end_week_date
    FROM table
    WHERE Purchase_Date>= DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), WEEK(MONDAY)) AND Purchase_Date<= DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE()-6, WEEK(SUNDAY))
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your sample data does not match your desired output.  [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CTEs to compute the auxiliary data you need. With your starting dataset, I would do the following:

```
with data as (
   select
      User_ID,
      Purchase_Date,
      DATE_TRUNC(Purchase_Date, WEEK(MONDAY)) as start_week_date,
      DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(Purchase_Date, WEEK(MONDAY)), INTERVAL 6 DAY) as end_week_date,
   from your_database
)

select distinct
   count(distinct User_ID) over (partition by first_day_week, last_day_week) as Unique_User_ID_Count,
   first_day_week,
   last_day_week,
from data
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need is something like this..

```
select 
DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DateField)+1, convert(int,DateField)),DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DateField)+7, convert(int,DateField)),count(*)
from Table1

group by DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DateField)+1, convert(int,DateField)),DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DateField)+7, convert(int,DateField))
```

if the data is big.. i d convert date to float then div to 7 then convert to int.. which i think can group the same results.. but then you are gonna have some more trouble in frontend..